# Bash scripting testing for existing file with arbitrary extension in a while or for loop

Tags: file, bash, testing, scripting

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while.  I've read through multiple threads, and feel like I'm close, but the script just isn't coming together.

Scenario:
I have a media server and thousands of movie files.  Each movie file has various accessory files such as the Cover artwork, Database info, Fanart, and trailer.  While everything in the directory has it's coverart and database info, some files may or may not have their respective fanart or trailer.  For these files I'm trying to get this script working which will create an empty "dummy" file in place of the file that should be there.  Then when I actually have the time I can go back and search out just the dummy files and work to fill in the gaps where I can.

Here is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' movie ; 
do
echo $movie
    moviename=${movie%\.*} #remove the extension from the string
    moviename1=`echo $moviename | sed 's/\ /\\ /'` #add escaped spaces to the string
    echo $moviename1  #echo the string (for debugging)
    if [ ! -f $moviename-fanart* ]; #because the fanart could be .jpg, or .png, etc
    then
        echo "Creating $moviename-fanart.dummy"
        touch "$moviename-fanart.dummy"
    fi
    if [ ! -f $moviename-trailer* ]; #because tralers could be .mp4, .mov, .mkv, .avi, etc
    then
        echo "Creating $moviename-trailer.dummy"
        touch "$moviename-trailer.dummy"
    fi
done
```

This should be pretty simple, but I think that I'm not getting the proper formating for the input string going into the test operators.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What isn't working about it? Is it not correctly creating the dummy files, or is it just not finding where they are supposed to go?

Answer (score 1):

Line-by-line analysis:

```
find . -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' movie; do
```

OK, but with bash4 you can just use `shopt -s globstar` to operate recursively on a directory.

```
    moviename=${movie%\.*} #remove the extension from the string
```

You don't need the backslash.

```
    moviename1=`echo $moviename | sed 's/\ /\\ /'` #add escaped spaces to the string
```

This line is suspect because if you *quote* the name, escaped spaces become doubly-escaped. You're confusing the *value* of the string with the representation you see of it.

```
    if [ ! -f $moviename-fanart* ]; then #because the fanart could be .jpg, or .png, etc
```

Quote the string or use bash's `[[` test keyword. It's a little dangerous to expand a glob inside the test expression because if it matches multiple results you'll get an error. That said, if you're sure there can be only one you can quote *up to* the glob. `"$moviename-fanart"*`.

```
        touch "$moviename-fanart.dummy"
```

Here, you quote it. So essentially you're dealing with a different name now.

```
    fi
    if [ ! -f $moviename-trailer* ]; then #because tralers could be .mp4, .mov, .mkv, .avi, etc
        echo "Creating $moviename-trailer.dummy"
        touch "$moviename-trailer.dummy"
    fi
```

Same thing.

```
done
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks.  I'll report back.

Comment: `globstar` will result in slightly different behavior than the given `find` command, in that it will also match directories.

Comment: @chepner if all movies do have an extension and all directories don't, you could: `for movies in **/*.*`.(You could even test for files with `-f` ;-)

Comment: @MikeJ Please accept the answer if it help! At kojiro: great work!